# How should I enable the trace log for ALSA hda_unsol_event?

Tags: alsa, debugging

I have reported an ALSA kernel [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68071) and have been [asked](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68071#c26) to "enable tracepoints" and "check the response of hda_unsol_event". I was directed to the [kernel docs for instruction](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/tree/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio.txt), which say:

> [image]

Except when I ran the commands (as root), I did not get the desired output ([what I got](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=122351)) ([what I was supposed to get](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/160462582/trace.log)). I don't know exactly what the differences between the two logs but it seems that:

- The desired output should only have the tasks `alsa-sync` or `kworker`; and entries in the FUNCTION column that begin with `hda_`, and
- Mine has lots of tasks, like `plasma-desktop`, `knotify`, and tons of other tasks, and in the FUNCTION column the only thing is `do_sys_open`.

What am I supposed to do to trace `hda_unsol_event`? The docs are not very clear, as you can see...

Comment: Are you running these commands as root?

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you did/didn't get? Those logs are long and I'm not really sure what we should be looking at. Feel free to pull the key lines out (if there are any) and include them directly in the Q.

Comment: I expanded on that in the question as requested. Now removing previous comments for tidiness.